# How to deliver an image array from python to Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, image-processing

I am new to the world of Web Developing, i am currently using Ruby on Rails to code my webpages.

Here is the problem i am facing right now.
I am trying to make a webapp (using ruby on rails) in which the user must submit an Image(i am using CarrierWave for this) and the program its suppose to do some image processing, recognized objects and count them, so for this task i made a python script which do this automatically(using OpenCV). My problem is that the python script must return a new image which has the objects of interest in rectangles, and then i must store it in the dabase.
Currently i am returning in console where my objects are in the image, and displaying the new image, but i am not able to return the image as an array so that ruby framework can process it and upload it.

[A simple view at how i am doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPaW4.png)

In the example[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPaW4.png) i am recognizing oranges in the trees.

If anyone can help me or have an idea at how to do it, maybe a different approach could work. I am new in this, i have researched everywhere with no goods results. I didn't want to pose any code because i dont know which part is useful or not. (sorry for my bad english, i am not use to it completely)

Comment: Does your Python script have to store the image in a db? Could it just save the image to the server and have your RoR backend grab it from there? The database could hold the file path of the image in it.

Comment: What do you mean with returning an image as an array? An image is a binary. You can save it to a file and pretty much load that back into any language. I don't see the issue you are having.

Comment: the image supposed itself in script or url is okay to fetch from host ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save an image locally into python you need to make an Image object and then save it to a given path.

```
my_image= Image("simplecv")
my_image.save("my-image.png") # in the current working directory
```

or to a path :

```
my_image.save("path/to/img.png")
```

You can then re-load those files with another language and store them in a database.

More examples on : 
http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/basics.html